# Laravel 5.0 Sweet Alert Class 'UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlertServiceProvider' not found

Tags: notifications, laravel-5

please i have done these :

- "require": { 
     "uxweb/sweet-alert": "~1.1",
  }
- 'providers' => [
       'UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlertServiceProvider::class'
    ]
- 'aliases' => [
        'Alert'     => UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlert::class
    ]

but i keep getting the error.

Comment: did you use that in your controller also? If you haven't, add `use Alert` at the top of your controller

Comment: did you run `composer update`?

Comment: @Kryten Yeah av run composer update like 4 times now.

Comment: @Sid, immediately i refresh my page, the error comes up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working under proxy therefore my internet connection was not working in the command line hence,

> composer update
>   Was not working